# Validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

The below code to validate `TextBox` is working fine `onkeypress` but when I use `backspace` to reduce the text length this code is unable to return back to the RED color. How to change color back to `red` on using `backspace` to reduce string length.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function limitlength(obj, length) {
        var maxlength = length
        if (obj.value.length > maxlength) {
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

    }

</script>

Enter text (max length is 5 characters):
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeypress="return limitlength(this, 5)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `onchange` or `onkeyup`.
I think it's better if you use `onkeyup`

Answer (score 1):

try using ***onkeydown*** or ***onkeyup*** event.